# pandas date assignment destroy other columns

Tags: python, pandas

In Python 2.7.11 + Pandas 0.14.1, enlargement assignment with a column of datetime64[ns] seems to corrupt existing columns. Anyone can kindly explain what happened here ? Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ss=pd.Series(data=['1/1/2000','1/2/2000','1/3/2000','1/4/2000','1/5/2000','1/6/2000'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((6,2)))
print df

       0         1
 0  0.176862  0.234371
 1  0.335773  0.885695
 2  0.186647  0.205853
 3  0.362603  0.702148
 4  0.649333  0.017222
 5  0.161256  0.705346


sss = pd.to_datetime(ss)
print sss
df.loc[:,'date'] = sss
print df 

       0          1         date
  0 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 2000-01-01
  1 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 2000-01-02
  2 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 2000-01-03
  3 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 2000-01-04
  4 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 2000-01-05
  5 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 2000-01-06
```

Comment: try `df['date'] = sss` instead of `df.loc[:,'date'] = sss`. PS your code works properly in pandas 0.18.1

Comment: @MaxU: Yes, using df['date']=sss gives correct result in pandas 0.14.1. Could you explain why?

Comment: Probably using the two-index assignment `[..., ....]` instead of `[...]` triggers some kind of datatype recalculation.  The normal way to add a column is `df['newcolumn'] = newdata`; there's no reason to use `df[:, 'newcolumn']` to add a new column.

Comment: @BrenBarn: actually, the pandas doc [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) uses  .loc[:,'newcolumn'] for setting with enlargement too. It's rather surprising the documented way doesn't work.

Comment: @user2658138 The first thing you should do is update pandas, unless that was  typo. As most people are not running your version.